# Add tags or annotations to text files

Tags: nautilus, tag, annotation

I have a lot of similar text files - data in csv format etc. - that differ only in minor aspects (data normalized or not normalized...). It is very difficult to find meaningful names for the different files that allow me to keep track of what I did within each of them. Is there a way to add a comment or tags to these files in nautilus or with an additional program?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags will show up in Nautilus as little emblems that are displayed on top of the files' icons.

**Write a file tag:**

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string 'PATH-TO-FILE.csv' metadata::annotation "This is a sample file annotation."
```

**Read a file tag:**

```
gvfs-info -a metadata::annotation 'PATH-TO-FILE.csv'
```

**Example:** For a file called FILE.csv that is located on your desktop 'PATH-TO-FILE.csv' would be `'~/Desktop/FILE.csv'`. The easy way to generate 'PATH-TO-FILE.csv' automatically, including the 2 apostrophe characters, is to simply drag the file's icon from the file manager into an open terminal.

---

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

Support for emblems in the default Ubuntu repositories is back in 14.04 and later. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-emblems
```

To add an emblem to a file or folder right-click its icon, and from the popup context menu select *Properties* -> *Emblems* tab -> select an emblem to add. Navigate to a different directory and then back again to view the emblem that was changed.

[image: IMG:]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much! This will definitely help me a lot. I was hoping that there was a way to do this directly in nautilus, or at least to read the annotation directly in nautilus. Is there an add-on or another possibility to add these things to the context menu in nautilus? Thanks!

Comment: The PPA for [nautilus-actions-extra](https://launchpad.net/~nae-team/+archive/ppa) contains a Python program called _emblemize_ that can add file emblems directly from Nautilus. The reason why I use my code instead of emblemize is that I didn't want to add an untrusted PPA to my system. Instructions for installing emblemize are found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2052617.html).